Unusual Error When Using nn.Sequential in Model Class in PyTorch
Just creating a simple neural network here to try out nn.Sequential, for some reason i'm getting this error
Here is the code:
# Create Model

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Define Network

        self.stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=8),

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(in_features=8, out_features=8),

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(in_features=8, out_features=1),

            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # Define Forward Pass

        return self.stack(x)


# Instance Of Model

model = Net(X_train[:5])


Error Here:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-f947c74336f3> in <cell line: 31>()
     29 # Instance Of Model
     30 
---> 31 model = Net(X_train[0])

TypeError: Net.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


Here I tried to test if my model worked by inputting the first 5 values of my training data, instead of getting 5 numbers between 0 and 1, ex. [0.1, 0.2, 0.43, 0.67, .78] I get the error above.

You are passing your input to the model constructor. You need to instantiate the model before calling the forward method.
model = Net()
out = model(torch.randn(8, 3))


You're getting that error because you're passing the input tensor "too early." Calling Net() semantically is "model creation" when the model object is created and initialized, but your model doesn't exist yet! Model execution just right after model creation will be:
Net()(X_train[:5])
But usually, we do it in 2 steps:
# Create model
model = Net()
# Now you can call model multiple times...
model(X_train[:5])

